# extract sequences from python list

Tags: python, list, sequence, sequences

I have a list in python which looks like this:

```
['x','x','x','x','P','x','x','N','P','N','x','x','x','N','P','x','x,'x,','x','x','x','N','x,'x','P','N','x','x','x'....]
```

I need to process the list in some way such that I return individual sequences of `P` and `N`. In the above case I need to return:

```
[['P'],['N','P','N'],['N','P'],['N'],['P','N'].....]
```

I have looked at `itertools` but have not found anything that can do this. I have a lot of lists to process in this way so efficiency is also important.

Comment: Did you try to come up with this algorithm yourself?

Comment: What does "a lot of lists" mean (e.g. more than 10³ or more than 10⁹)?How large are they (e.g. more than 10³ or more than 10⁹ elements/bytes)? What are your performance requirements? A naive implementation can be done in less than 10 lines of code, but recommending solutions is difficult without answers to these questions.

Comment: There are ~100,000 lists of average length 500. I think Thierry Latuille answer will do the trick! thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['x','x','x','x','P','x','x','N','P','N','x','x','x','N',
        'P','x','x','x','x','x','x','N','x','x','P','N','x','x','x']

out = list(list(g) for k, g in groupby(data, lambda item: item in {'N', 'P'}) if k)

print(out)
# [['P'], ['N', 'P', 'N'], ['N', 'P'], ['N'], ['P', 'N']]
```

We group according to `item in {'N', 'P'}`, and keep only the groups for which this is True.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    main_list = []
    def get_desired_value(_list):
        new_list = []
        for val in _list:
            if val in ['N', 'P']:
                new_list.append(val)
            else:
                if new_list:
                    main_list.append(new_list[:])
                    new_list.clear()
        return main_list
   print(get_desired_value(data))
   >>>[['P'], ['N', 'P', 'N'], ['N', 'P'], ['N'], ['P', 'N']]
```